# Leaderboard with accumulated points using Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to set a leaderboard just like the stackoverflow user reputation listing page does.

https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week

Everytime a user starts a new game his score will be added to his previous game score. Means the score will be accumulated. When i set a new highscore google play will update all three leaderboards(daily, weekly and alltime). The alltime part is OK. But the daily and weekly leaderboard values must be calculated seperately. Can i select which time period to be updated or at least disable the daily and weekly leaderboards?

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem, I am facing the same issue with my app

Comment: No. You just need to keep track of it locally and send the server the updated score. But unfortunately you can't have the daily and weekly scores.

Answer (score 2):

Here is issue on google code:

https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=59&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Platform%20Summary%20Stars